# Fill an integer array with a series of number that is a string (java)

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to write the following program, where i have a string that a number is generated possibly like 37 digits.
Is it possible to fill an array that i know the length but not the rows because the string can be anything.

```
String number;  //110034043312132121220023020423340432   but can be any big number that is converted to a string 

System.out.println("Give length in a form of a string: ");  
String input= scan.nextLine();    //abcdefg
int length = input.length();      //this means i get 6 back.
```

And save this in a character array where i know the length from input.lenght() and i dont know the rows

```
A B C D E F G
1 1 0 0 3 4 0
4 3 3 1 2 1 3
2 1 2 1 2 2 0
0 2 3 0 2 0 4
2 3 3 4 0 4 3
2
```

I know the answer might be something stupid simple but please be coder noob friendly. Thanks

Comment: The A B C D E F G wont be saved in the char array, only the numbers.

Comment: 1, Length of `abcdefg` is 7 not 6.  2. Do you need to save `char` digits `0`, `1`... `9` or actual digits 0, 1.. 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be as follows:

1. Use `input.length` as the max number of columns in the resulting 2D array
2. Calculate the number of rows in the resulting 2D array `nums / cols`, adding one extra row if there's a remainder.
3. The last row in the result may be jagged: contain less than `cols` elements.

```java
String number = "110034043312132121220023020423340432"; //   but can be any big number that is converted to a string 

System.out.println("Give length in a form of a string: ");  
String input= "ABCDEFG" ; //scan.nextLine();    //abcdefg
int cols = input.length(); // columns in the resulting array
int nums = number.length(); // total count of numbers

int rows = nums / cols + (nums % cols == 0 ? 0 : 1);
int[][] result = new int[rows][]; // the result may be jagged

for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    result[i] = new int[cols];
}
result[rows - 1] = new int[nums % cols == 0 ? cols : nums % cols];

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    int r = i / cols;
    int c = i % cols;
    result[r][c] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
}

// print the result
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(".", "$0 ")); // print header with spaces between columns
for (int[] row : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)
                             .replaceAll("[^\\s\\d]", "") // remove brackets and comma from output
    );
}
```

Output:

```
A B C D E F G 
1 1 0 0 3 4 0
4 3 3 1 2 1 3
2 1 2 1 2 2 0
0 2 3 0 2 0 4
2 3 3 4 0 4 3
2
```

Comment: This was very helpful!  Also i don't quite understand the use of ? and : in the 
int rows = nums / cols + (nums % cols == 0 ? 0 : 1); 
and everywhere else that is being used. Is there a simpler way of writing it? Or that's the only way? Thanks.

Comment: It is a ternary operator (see ["The Conditional Operators" section here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)), which is a _shortcut_ for the more verbose `if-else` statement: `int remainder; if (nums % cols == 0) remainder = 0; else remainder = 1;  int rows = nums / cols + remainder;`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you might be able to use a list instead.

`ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();`

and in each line, you can add a new array into the list.
If you want the final result to be a 2d array, you can easily convert a list to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[][] createMatrix(String num, String title) {
    int totalRows = (int)Math.ceil((double)num.length() / title.length());
    char[][] matrix = new char[totalRows + 1][title.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++)
        matrix[0][i] = title.charAt(i);

    for (int i = 0, row = 1, col = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        matrix[row][col++] = num.charAt(i);

        if (col == matrix[row].length) {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `double` math, stick with `int` math, and rely on integer division truncating the result: `totalRows = (num.length() + title.length() - 1) / title.length();`

Comment: *FYI:* OP added [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508149/fill-an-integer-array-with-a-series-of-number-that-is-a-string-java#comment114065023_64508149): *The A B C D E F G wont be saved in the char array, only the numbers.*